# Can we merge-synonym [having] and [having-clause] tags in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The tags [having](/questions/tagged/having) and [having-clause](/questions/tagged/having-clause) look similar to me. Both seem to be used for [Having Clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

Should these be merged?

Comment: [having-clause].  Ick.  It really should be something like [sql-having], but the name management tools that mods have access to are like using flint to start a fire, when a lighter would do a much better job.